# Public Groups - Updating "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" Setting

Tags: apex, standard-objects, public-group, standard-field

Can anyone tell me if the `DoesIncludeBosses` field is the back end for the front end checkbox of `Grant Access Using Hierarchies` for Public Groups? Documentation doesn't connect the two together.

I want to do a mass update and remove the setting from all of our Public Groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is what that field does. I went through the UI and checked/unchecked it on a group, and the value of that field changed accordingly.

**`DoesincludeBosses = true`**

[image: Checked]

**`DoesincludeBosses = false`**

[image: Unchecked]

Comment: Ha, thanks Adrian, I guess I could have done that on my own, if I had just thought through it! Yikes, long day.